# Custom fiber optic cable simulation

Tags: manufacturing, optics, optical-fibre, manufacturing-process

I am looking to create a custom & precise static optical distribution along the length of a fiber optic cable. The idea involves manipulating an optical fiber during manufacturing to produce the distribution along it's length. I want to simulate this concept to see if the optical properties of the modified fiber optic cable are what I expect them to be prior to manufacturing the fiber.

The end goal is to create a tool that utilizes this technology, but at this stage I am looking into testing a minimal proof-of-concept.

Would you know which software tools are typically used to accomplish a feasibility analysis of optical characteristics on a fiber-optic scale?

Comment: You're well off topic, I think, but Lighttools is what our optical engineering department teaches, and my students have used it for this sort of stuff.  http://optics.synopsys.com/lighttools/

Comment: ... and if you're looking at expensive prototyping, I suggest that finding an optical engineer to consult might be worth your time and money.